# How to OrderBy using Linq with missing elements?

Tags: c#, linq

Usually when using Linq I would usually filter out empty/null records using Where or similar. However, I need to order a List on multiple criteria and retain all items in the list but in order.

The following works only when `.Dimension1.Count > 0` for all items in the list

```
var orderedList = mList.Elements
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Property1)
                       .ThenBy(x => x.Property2)
                       .ThenBy(x => x.Property3.Dimension1[0].Value2)
                       .ToList();
```

If any  of the elements have `Dimension1.Count == 0` then I get error:

> 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Which is expected as the array is not dimensioned.

Is there a way to make this work when the list contains items which have `.Dimension1.Count = 0`?

Note that `Dimension1[0].Value2` is type double.

Comment: What if `.Dimension1.Count > 1`?

Comment: try this out if the type is nullable.  `x.Property3.Dimension1.FirstOrDefault()?.Value2`

Comment: I need to sort by the value inside the array `Dimension1[0].Value2` but some of these array elements do not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var orderedList = mList.Elements.OrderBy(x => x.Property1)
.ThenBy(x => x.Property2)
.ThenBy(x => x.Property3.Dimension1.Count == 0
    ? -1
    : x.Property3.Dimension1[0].Value2)
.ToList();
```

I am assuming here that `Value2` is an integer. If it is a string for example, you can use `null` instead of `-1`.

The idea is that you use a special value when `Count` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether you're using, for example, Entity Framework. It's doubtful this would convert to a valid SQL statement (it might..), but this may be worth a try in your case.

```
.ThenBy(x => x.Property3.Dimension1[0].Count > 0 ? x.Property3.Dimension1[0].Value2 : -1)
```

I'm assuming `Value2` is always `> 0`, so that any records missing values should be assigned `-1` and be pushed further down the list. If that's not the case, you may need to change `-1` to something more appropriate to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide a default value for the second `ThenBy`.

```
.ThenBy(x => x.Property3.Dimension1.Any() 
             ? x.Property3.Dimension1[0].Value2 
             : // Some default value for the type of Value2.
               // Go high or low depending on the type to put 
               // them at the top or bottom of the list
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be sure that will not be null exception for Dimensions1 array:

```
.Then(x => (x.Property3.Dimensions1 ?? new object[0]).Count > 0 ? x.Property3.Dimensions1[0].Value2 : -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated LINQ method for that, [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx), which

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value
>   in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

```
var orderedList = mList.Elements
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Property1)
                       .ThenBy(x => x.Property2)
                       .ThenBy(x => x.Property3.Dimension1.DefaultIfEmpty(someDefaultValue).ElementAt(0).Value2)
                       .ToList();
```